# Service Fabric SDK installation

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am facing a problem while installing **MS Service Fabric SDK 2.7.198 using Web Installer 5.0 for Visual Studio 2017 v15.2**, previously I had installed other versions of SF on different or on same system and it was installed without any problem. But this time I am unable to install it and installation is failed and message says **Service Fabric Runtime version 5.7.198.9494 need to be install**. I have installed it using Visual Studio installer. Please suggest where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Uninstall and re install the visual studio with azure service fabric tools resolved the problem.

Comment: post that as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall and re install the visual studio with azure service fabric tools resolved the problem.

Answer (score -3):

[image]

I have install only runtime this way. Hope this will help you to install runtime only.